# Cd inside a Bash FUNCTION

Tags: linux, bash, function, shell, cd

My first question on SO, so apologies if not doing something right!

There are many questions on the internet about using cd inside a script, but my problem is in using cd inside a bash function I put in my `.bashrc`. Its task is to find a file and go to the working directory of the file. In case of multiple files found, I just goes to the first one. Here it is:

```
fcd() {
cd $PWD
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo 'Specify a file name to find'
else
    found_dir=$( find . -name $1 -type f -printf \"%h/\" -quit )
    echo $found_dir
    if [ -z "$found_dir" ]; then
        echo "No file found. Directory was not changed"
    else
        cd $found_dir
    fi
fi
}
```

However, when I use it, the directory is found, but trying to `cd $found_dir` results in the message:

```
cd: (directory_here): No such file or directory
```

I've excluded possibility of the path being wrong - by copying the output of `echo $found_dir` and pasting it in front of a `cd` the directory is changed succesfully. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jakub

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not quote the directory in the find command, you should quote it later, when you use the variable. So change the find command from

```
find . -name $1 -type f -printf \"%h/\" -quit
```

to

```
find . -name "$1" -type f -printf %h -quit
```

The first command returns the directory path surrounded by quotes, as in `"/path/to/dir"`. So when you try to `cd` to that directory, `cd` will think that the quotes are part of the path.

Then adjust the `cd` to `cd "$found_dir"` to ensure that `cd` will not fail if `$found_dir` contains special characters such as space or a `*`.

Also note that the `cd $PWD` is redundant as we are already in that directory. Actually, it might even cause a problem since you are not quoting the variable.

Comment: Oh yes, the cd $PWD was my silly debugging attempt. Your solution worked, you guys are the best!